# Python port forwarding with dynamic SOCKs

Tags: python, proxy, paramiko, portforwarding, pysocks

I has been trying to create a port forwarding session including a dynamic socks with paramiko and pysocks, I already do it with plink using this:

`plink -ssh -D 10100 -L 25000:PrivateServerIP:1494 user@RemoteServerIP`

I am trying this but isn't working:

```
import paramiko
from getpass import getpass
import socks

USERNAME= 'username'
SERVER_IP = '138.x.x.x'
PRIVATE_IP = '10.x.x.x'
OTP = getpass()

def main():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=SERVER_IP, username=signum, password=OTP)

    trans = client.get_transport()
    trans.open_channel("forwarded-tcpip", dest_addr = (PRIVATE_IP, 1494), src_addr = ('', 25000))
    
    s = socks.socksocket() 
    s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "",10100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run plink command in background using subprocess and QNetworkProxy for my app:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork                                                                                                                                       
from subprocess import Popen

user = 'user'
ip = 'x.x.x.x'
passwd = 'passwd'
dynamicPort = 10100
sshPort = 22
proxyHostName = 'localhost'

cmnd = f'plink -batch -ssh -D {dynamicPort} -P {sshPort} {user}@{ip} -pw "{passwd}" "while [ True ]; do sleep 300;echo Keeping alive; done"'
Popen(cmnd,shell=True)     
        

class magic(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(magic, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        loadUi('file.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
                

def main(args):
    proxy = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy()
    proxy.setType(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy)
    proxy.setHostName(proxyHostName)
    proxy.setPort(dynamicPort)
    QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
    app = QApplication(args)
    a = magic()
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).